# send message to twitter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, twitter

I want to post a message in `twitter`.

This is the code which I am using currently:

```
public void PostTweets(string userName, string password, string updateMessage)
{
   using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
   {
      wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
      ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

      byte[] updateMessageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("status=" + updateMessage); //Use UTF8 to get it properly encoded if you use characters like ç ã etc...

      wc.UploadData("https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuse/update",updateMessageBytes);
   }
}
```

It's giving me a error like:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Comment: Clearly you've not supplied the correct credentials. Are you sure the user name and password are correct?

Comment: yes..credentials are correct...

Comment: Is there any possible to post tweet without using consumer key and consumer token, access token and keys... I want to post tweet using my twitter username and password....

Comment: no, twitter will only accept oauth (key and token) and will no longer accept username and password... it's been like this for quite a while.

Comment: @KutF Is there any way to get oauth tokens using Username and password through programatically..

Comment: I follow this code.Again Ia ma getting same error  http://gvvtech.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/how-to-implement-a-twitter-desktop-client-in-c-net-using-xauth-authentication/    Please any one can solve my problem...

Comment: @Gowri no, since the article you mention (2010) twitter changed to oauth. the example you are working towards is out of date.